# missing translation i18n, return only the key

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm newbie on I18n technique, but I have configured my node.js like this:

*server.js*

```
 const i18n = require('./locales/i18n');
    ...
    const app = express();
    app.use(i18n.init);
    ....
    ....
    //just for testing....
    console.log('i18n.getLocale().before:', i18n.getLocale())
    i18n.setLocale('it')
    console.log('i18n.getLocale().after:', i18n.getLocale()) 
    console.log('login.error:', i18n.__('login.error409'))

app.listen(port, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else
        console.log(" server running", port);
});
```

when I try to run my application by the command **node server.js** I get this output:

```
....
....
i18n.getLocale().before: en
i18n.getLocale().after: it
login.error: login.error409
...
...
```

the file of configuration are this:

*i18n.js*

```
const i18n = require('i18n');
const { join } = require('path');

/**
 * later in code configure
 */
i18n.config ={
    // setup some locales - other locales default to en silently
    locales: ['en', 'fr', 'al', 'es', 'it'],
   
    // fallback from Dutch to German and from any localized German (de-at, de-li etc.) to German
    //fallbacks: { nl: 'de', 'de-*': 'de' },
   
    // you may alter a site wide default locale
    defaultLocale: 'en',
   
    // will return translation from defaultLocale in case current locale doesn't provide it
    retryInDefaultLocale: false,
   
    // sets a custom cookie name to parse locale settings from - defaults to NULL
    //cookie: 'yourcookiename',
   
    // sets a custom header name to read the language preference from - accept-language header by default
    header: 'accept-language',
   
    // query parameter to switch locale (ie. /home?lang=ch) - defaults to NULL
    queryParameter: 'lang',
   
    // where to store json files - defaults to './locales' relative to modules directory
    directory: join(__dirname, '.', 'locales'),
   
    // control mode on directory creation - defaults to NULL which defaults to umask of process user. Setting has no effect on win.
    //directoryPermissions: '755',
   
    // watch for changes in JSON files to reload locale on updates - defaults to false
    //autoReload: true,
   
    // whether to write new locale information to disk - defaults to true
    //updateFiles: false,
   
    // sync locale information across all files - defaults to false
    //syncFiles: false,
   
    // what to use as the indentation unit - defaults to "\t"
    indent: '\t',
   
    // setting extension of json files - defaults to '.json' (you might want to set this to '.js' according to webtranslateit)
    extension: '.json',
   
    // setting prefix of json files name - default to none '' (in case you use different locale files naming scheme (apiwebapp-en.json), rather then just en.json)
    prefix: 'apiwebapp-',
   
    // enable object notation
    objectNotation: false,
   
    // setting of log level DEBUG - default to require('debug')('i18n:debug')
    logDebugFn: function (msg) {
      console.log('debug', msg)
    },
   
    // setting of log level WARN - default to require('debug')('i18n:warn')
    logWarnFn: function (msg) {
      console.log('warn', msg)
    },
   
    // setting of log level ERROR - default to require('debug')('i18n:error')
    logErrorFn: function (msg) {
      console.log('error', msg)
    },
   
    // used to alter the behaviour of missing keys
    missingKeyFn: function (locale, value) {
      return value
    },
   
    // object or [obj1, obj2] to bind the i18n api and current locale to - defaults to null
    register: global,
   
    // hash to specify different aliases for i18n's internal methods to apply on the request/response objects (method -> alias).
    // note that this will *not* overwrite existing properties with the same name
    api: {
      __: 't', // now req.__ becomes req.t
      __n: 'tn' // and req.__n can be called as req.tn
    },
   
    // When set to true, downcase locale when passed on queryParam; e.g. lang=en-US becomes en-us.
    // When set to false, the queryParam value will be used as passed;
    // e.g. lang=en-US remains en-US.
    preserveLegacyCase: true, // defaults to true
   
    // set the language catalog statically
    // also overrides locales
    // staticCatalog: {
    //   de: {
    //     /* require('de.json') */
    //   }
    // },
   
    // use mustache with customTags (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache#custom-delimiters) or disable mustache entirely
    mustacheConfig: {
      tags: ['{{', '}}'],
      disable: false
    }
};


i18n.configure(i18n.config);

module.exports = i18n;
```

and the JSON file for translation are this:

*/api/locales/apiwebapp-it.json*

```
{
        "login": {
            "error409": "no account found!"
        }
    }
```

I can't be able to translate...

**EDIT**

I change this line

```
directory: join(__dirname, '.', 'locales'),
```

to this

```
directory: join(__dirname),
```

and this solve the problem of directory files and the I change the JSON language like this:

```
{
    "login.error409": "no account found!"
}
```

Comment: Does it work for other languages you have set up? _(in case it might just be a file location issue)_

Comment: no, all languages not respond, in the console.log return always the name of the key and not the string translated